# Does it make if difference if an interface property is marked abstract or not?

Tags: c#, interface

Consider the following code:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    public string Property { get; }
    public abstract string AbstractProperty { get; }
}
```

Does it make a difference if one adds the `abstract` keyword or not? Guess it's just explicit, but the property is implicitly abstract anyway?

Comment: In the example code, `abstract` doesn't make a difference. In the documentation in ["Interfaces summary"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces#interfaces-summary) it says "... an interface is like an abstract base class with only abstract members." (C# 8 and C# 11 added language changes to interfaces but those changes don't bear on the given example code.)

Comment: Apparently, since C# 8.0, interface declarations can contain some redundant clauses. Previously, it was illegal to specify either `public` or `abstract` on interface methods, now they just have no effect.

Comment: thanks for your inputs :-) one of you should post as answer :-)

Comment: See my answer in the dupe target. It doesn't make a difference here, but it does make a difference when interfaces start to inherit each other.